# Theoretical Phonemes

Tags: linguistics, phonology, phonetics, ipa

I have been looking at IPA recently and I was wondering if there are any sounds that can theoretically be created by humans but do not exist or have not existed in any known languages. Or maybe a sound that is unique to one language or is very rare nonetheless. This has been bugging me for ages now and I will really appreciate any responses on the subject.

Comment: Certainly there are, eg, "guttural" sounds that are not used in English or any European languages that I know of, though I understand they are present in some African languages.  And I can do a pretty good Donald Duck "quack" that I doubt could be represented in IPA.  Additionally, understand that a "minor" pronunciation variation that might be ignored in one language may be extraordinarily significant in another language.

Comment: This question belongs on linguistics.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as Peter says it belongs on linguistics.SE.

Answer (score 3):

Phoneticians categorize sounds by describing the positions and movements of the parts of the human sound-making apparatus -- tongue, lips, teeth, nose, vocal cords, etc. -- and the movement of air through these parts.  Some of those combinations are physically impossible (e.g., you could make a sound far enough back in your throat that you couldn't get air through your nose), and some of them aren't usually possible (e.g., I'm given to understand that some people can trill, that is vibrate, their cheeks), and the sound of the latter is unlikely to exist in any spoken language.

Some similar sounds don't make a difference.  For instance, in English, we aspirate the **k** in ***k**ill* but not in *s**k**ill*, but the two different **k** sounds don't distinguish words.  So if you deliberately forced yourself not to aspirate the **k** when you said *kill*, English speakers would still understand the threat.  The two **k**'s are called allophones, and I don't know whether you want to count the multiples as "sounds in a language."  They are, just not significant ones.

You're asking for the proof of a negative.  There are a lot of languages that nobody knows about -- some extinct, some yet to be discovered -- so a definitive statement will be hard to come by.   That said, you may go [here](https://m.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/3jz35b/are_there_anywhat_are_some_examples_of_consonants/) for a discussion of unused sounds, although I can't vouch for the expertise of the writers, but there the claim is made that there no phonemic ingressive velar trills (the sound of snoring).  Go [here](https://youtu.be/7G5o1iAoyPY) to see (and hear) a performance of many of the sounds claimed not to exist in language

Sounds very unlikely to be phonemes in any language are so-called "co-articulated" sounds -- separate sounds pronounced simultaneously, like the sound you can make of talking under water.  For a triple co-articulation go [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfQbZxW6MBE).

Comment: If you said *kill* with an unasirated **k**, wouldn't there be a good chance that an English speaker would think you said *gill*?

Comment: @bof mostly not, since the context would normally make it clear.

Comment: @bof The **k** is voiceless; the **g** is voiced.

Comment: Yes, I know. The **g** in *gill* is voiced and unaspirated; the **k** in *kill* is unvoiced and aspirated. So an unaspirated **k** sounds kinda like **k** and kinda like **g** and might be misunderstood.

Comment: @bof We're a bit far from my point but you're right. The reason is that English distinguishes between aspirated and voiced stops.  The unaspirated voiced stops (like **g**) are actually produced as unaspirated voicless stops with a zero (or close to zero) voice onset time (i.e., the delay after the stop is released and the following vowel is sounded).  Which is why the Jimi Hendrix lyric *'Scuse me while I kiss the sky* has been misheard as *'Scuse me while I kiss this guy*.  So anyone trying to drop the aspiration in an initial *k* has to speak very  deliberately to avoid others hearing **g**

Comment: @deadrat Nice post. There's a bit more to that Hendrix example. Syllable onset /p,k,t/ are aspirated in English *unless* they're preceded by /s/. So in *the sky* the /k/ is *naturally* unaspirated and therefore /g/-like!